# Jade cache template and Node restart

Tags: node.js, express, pug

My setup:

Express 4.2.0

Jade 1.3.1

I'm learning express and jade templating.

I have a view, `mypage`, which display name and age vars defined in the route below.

Everytime I change the options args of `render` (changing name or age to anything), the `mypage view` doesn't get updated when I reload. So I always have to restart the node app (killing with ctrl+C and npm start) to get the last update.

It seems like it's caching, but I'm in development mode.

```
/* GET my page */
router.get('/mypage', function(req, res){
  res.render('mypage', {
    name: 'Default John',
    age: 213456
  });
});
```

I tried `app.disable('view cache')` and nothing. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: If you change your JavaScript code, the changes will not be updated until the script is reloaded; this is expected behaviour.  Maybe you're looking for something like [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon).

Comment: I see, this reminds me a 'compile step', except that it's a restart now. Ah, thanks for the nodemon link.

Comment: If you change only the Jade template instead, you can use the option `cache : false` to force the template to re-render on reload (no server restart necessary).

Answer (score -3):

Try to use

```
app.set('view cache', true);
```

Comment: app.set('view cache', false); in ur case